# how to get all dependencies of a library?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I want to use the Google Firebase Messaging library in my Android Project. But my laptop just works offline and has not any access to the internet. I want to download [FirebsaeMessaging](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-messaging/20.0.1) library with all it's dependencies then add those files as `aar library` files to my project. First I want to get list of all dependencies of that library. How can i do this without internet? Thanks.

Comment: So do you want to download the libraries to your laptop and _then_ work offline? Because at some point you need internet connection to download something ...

Comment: @JFMeier now I am using another system. I want to download those files with current system not that laptop. I want to copy downloaded files to my laptop!

Comment: I guess you can build your project on the system with internet to download the libraries and then copy/paste to the other system. In Maven, you can use the `-o` to build on an offline system.

Comment: @JFMeier Is not there any web sites for this purpose?

Comment: I guess today the majority of software expects you to be connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my [dependency-export](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-dependency-export) plugin to export dependencies to a directory using maven directory conventions. You can then use the directory as a local repository for building offline.

As of Gradle version 6.1 the dependency cache is portable meaning that you can copy the dependency cache from one machine to another and the second machine should be able build offline. Perhaps this is what you want?

See [this issue](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1338)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches in general:

1. You download the complete dependencies with your online system, copy them into a `libs` folder and then create a project where you dependent on every jar in that `libs` folder.
2. You create a maven based project, build the project so that every dependency is copied to your local repository and copy the `.m2` (local repository) to your offline machine. In case you want a gradle based project, @lance-java already posted a solution to that.

The first approach has the advantage that you have an isolated project with no dependency to the internet. Everything is in your project and explicit. You would have to check in your dependencies into your source control system like in good old times.

The second approach is good, if you are working in a team on that project. The export of your dependencies hat nothing to do with the project setup itself. Every programmer would find a "normal" project setup and dependency management.

If guess, that you want to go for the 1. way. If so, I would suggest to use [ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/download.cgi) to download the complete dependency tree. Put the `ivy-X.Y.Z.jar` into your project beside a script that lists all dependencies - some sort of poor mans dependency management.

Example:

```
$ java -jar ivy-2.5.0.jar -dependency com.google.firebase firebase-admin 6.8.1 -retrieve "libs/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]"
```

This command would download the complete dependency tree for `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1` and store the jars without version into the `libs` folder.